# SQL Error #1064 with Begin Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

**SQL**

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE gcm_users SET gcm_regid="fff" WHERE user_id=8;

  IF sql%rowcount = 0 THEN
      INSERT INTO gcm_users (gcm_regid, user_id) VALUES ("dsdtrytujytetgeryrtyh", "8");
  END IF;
END;
```

> Error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  'UPDATE gcm_users SET gcm_regid="dsdtrytujytetgeryrtyh" WHERE user_id=8' at line 2

**EDIT:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | user_id | gcm_regid | created_at          | Status |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 | 22      | ********* | 2015-04-25 13:13:39 |   1    |
|   2 | 33      | ********* | 2015-04-25 13:13:39 |   1    |
|   3 | 13      | ********* | 2015-04-25 13:13:39 |   1    |
|   4 | 12      | ********* | 2015-04-25 13:13:39 |   1    |
|   5 | 67      | ********* | 2015-04-25 13:13:39 |   1    |
|   6 | 65      | ********* | 2015-04-25 13:13:39 |   1    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone please help me fix this error?

Comment: Schema of `gcm_users` please?

Comment: Is this the full SQL or are you doing anything else outside of this BEGIN/END?

Comment: @xboxremote nothing else

Comment: @alagu: I'm not sure, but don't be there delimiter? Like `DELIMITER ;; BEGIN your code here END;;`?

Comment: That's what I was wondering. But I don't think it's needed unless he has more statements outside of the BEGIN/END block. But it may be worth a try?

Comment: if i remove BEGIN/END  i get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if sql%rowcount = 0 then INSERT INTO gcm_users (gcm_users, user_id).....

Comment: I seriously have no idea... Can you paste exactly what you're trying to run now that you took the BEGIN/END out? I want to see exactly what you're executing. Also, where are you executing this? Is it from some other application code or straight on the database? Are you using MySQL work bench or just command line PL/SQL?

Comment: I am excuting this code in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`), not double quotes (`"`):

```
begin
  UPDATE gcm_users SET gcm_regid='fff' WHERE user_id=8;

  if sql%rowcount = 0 then
      INSERT INTO gcm_users (gcm_users, user_id) 
      VALUES ('dsdtrytujytetgeryrtyh', 8);
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for you time but still i am getting the same error